# ZODB: unload an object (free it from memory)

Tags: python, plone, zodb

How do I proper manage ZODB's memory ?
I'm using ZODB to store data on my app (~1M products).

This very simple script make memory sky rockets (~4-5GB RAM on process monitor, computer begin use page file and freeze due to high disk write):

```
storage = FileStorage("data.fs")
db = DB(storage, cache_size=10, cache_size_bytes=2**20)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root()
products = root["products"] #product list

#Write all object to json
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    for id in products:
        f.write("%s\n" %products[id].to_json())
        #del products[id] #This return error
```

The del keyword won't work (as expect). How can I free products[id] from memory ?

Comment: Vote close. cacheMinimize() does help me. I still have some question though. Is there anyway to specify which object to be freed ? Why are cache_size and cache_size_bytes useless ?

Comment: The cache parameters are *target* cache sizes, but you cannot just clear objects out of memory during a transaction. A commit brings the cache back to the target size, or you can do this during a transaction, manually, when you know you won't need those objects anymore. The cache will keep most-recently-accessed objects (IIRC), you cannot tell it what to keep and what to flush, unless you modified objects (or manually set the `._p_changed` flags to `1` instead, at which point they'll be subject to writing to disk unless you revert the flag again before commit).